# How to install a MIDlet on a SonyEricsson phone directly in the Organizer folder

Tags: java-me, installation, midp, midlet, jad

This question refers strictly to Sony Ericsson phones running Java Platform 8 or higher. 
It is possible to instruct the AMS to install the application in one of the folders Applications or Games. But I want to install the MIDlet in a different folder. The target folders are Organizer, Entertainment or Location services. Is it possible to instruct the AMS to install my MIDlet in one of these folders?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see anything allowing this in SonyEricsson's proprietary AMS API.
That leaves only the jad properties and that only works for Applications vs Games.
Sorry. No luck there.